# what does two backslashs mean in jest's configuration

Tags: javascript, jestjs, regular-language

now i am learning jest to write unit tests. i have read part of the document of jest and some code on github about jest configuration, and i found that the option moduleNameMapper could be defined like:

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
    "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
    ".*\\.(css|less|scss)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js"
}
```

but i cannot understand what does "`\\`" mean in the configuration ?

it seems that two backslashs in a regular expression cannot match any file or directory.

i just wonder if such configuration can match like `"aaa.jpg"`, `"src/images/bbb.jpg"`, `"src/less/style.config.less"`, etc or not ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A backslash is an escape character in a regular expression and a string literal.

In the regex `\.` means a literal full stop character. Since the regex is inside a string literal, the `\` part of that needs escaping for the string parser.

```js
alert("My regex is: " + "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$")
```